# What are F# quotations?

Tags: f#, quotations

What are "quotations" in F#, and what are they used for?

Comment: They are used to make the novice F# programmer brain explode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In short, a quotation is metadata that represents the code of a particular function or code snippet.

http://fortysix-and-two.blogspot.com/2009/06/traversing-and-transforming-f.html

Answer (score 7):

See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx

and possibly

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity

If you want scenarios, I bet you can find some by looking at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/F%23+quotations

Answer (score 4):

They are equivalent to `Expression<>` objects in C#. They represent the expression tree of the code therein in a way that can be accessed by other code at runtime.

Comment: Do `Expression<>` objects actually quote code or are they just values representing code?