# Are F# quotations useful for anything?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, metaprogramming

I thought that I would be able to use quotations to accomplish what I'm trying to do (create a tree of expressions which I can store in a DB and execute later on). Much to my dismay, however, I've learned that quotations are not serializable and cannot be compiled (I would like to avoid F# PowerPack because the performance is bad).

So I'm curious to know, are F# quotations useful for anything at all? Of what use is a data structure representing code if it can't be compiled back into code? What am I missing here?

Related:
[Another limitation of F# quotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418000/another-limitation-of-f-quotations)
[What are F# quotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548395/what-are-f-quotations)

Comment: In F# 3.0 you no longer have to reference PowerPack to compile quotations. See [`LeafExpressionConverter.EvaluateQuotation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh324037.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: The Core lib also contains a function for converting `Expr<'T>` to `Expression<T>`. I bet you can find a good serialization library for LINQ expressions, if you're okay with storing them instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the MSDN article. I was hoping to avoid the overhead of the conversion to a LINQ expression but I guess I'll have to bite the bullet on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are useful for something.

Wikipedia says

> F# quotations are used for various purposes including to compile F# code to JavaScript and GPU code.

I've experimented with them and created a F#-Code to ActionScript compiler.